# Subclass UICollectionViewController with xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I'm trying to create a custom `UICollectionViewController` subclass.

I created it using Xcode's wizard:

[image: Screenshot 1]

and after clicking `Finish` I get this `.xib` file:

[image: Screenshot 2]

When I try to call it from another class like this:

```
MyCollectionViewController *myCollectionViewController = [MyCollectionViewController new];

[self addChildViewController:myCollectionViewController];

[self.view addSubview:myCollectionViewController.view];
```

I get this error:

```
UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter
```

If I use:

```
MyCollectionViewController *myCollectionViewController = [[MyCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[UICollectionViewFlowLayout new]];
```

it doesn't crashes but has some problems:

1. Why does it require an `CollectionViewLayout` if it is already in the `.xib` file?
2. I don't want to create the layout outside of `MyCollectionViewController`; what would be the purpose of subclassing in this case?
3. The whole view shows up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a view controller's UI is specified in a xib, then you have to instantiate it with a call to `[[MyCollectionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCollectionViewController" inBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]` (or however you get your bundle). When you use this constructor, then the view controller's outlets get wired up properly, and the layout is set based on what's in the xib.

Answer (score 0):

XIBs are *mostly* old-school, more so for view controllers. Use them for views, or sometimes cells. Since you're creating a view controller, use a storyboard instead. That has some advantages: you can configure the VC (and its view) in the storyboard; you can use auto-layout; and you can put related view controllers in the same storyboard.

With your storyboard file open, drag out a new UIViewController (or UICollectionViewController in this case), and on the 3rd properties tab (usually on the right), set your custom class.

Comment: I know, but I can't easily switch to storyboards. Also, there should be one storyboard for an entire project?

Comment: No, definitely not one per project. They get too unmaintainable, too unwieldy, too hard to merge changes. I use one for related VCs, e.g. An account login VC with a "recent accounts". Several in a project.

Comment: Also you don't have to switch wholesale to storyboards, you can keep your existing XIBs.